# Is the Native discarded when moving onto a Base Camp?

Tags: quest-for-el-dorado

In [The Quest for El Dorado](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/217372/quest-el-dorado), do you discard the Native card --

> The Native knows the lay of the land and always lets you move one
>   space when played. Ignore that space’s requirements and just place
>   your piece on it. The Native can also tear down blockades, but you
>   can’t use it to move to an occupied space or onto a mountain space.

-- when moving onto a Base Camp, or **does the Native card also ignore the Base Camp requirement**?

> Cards you play to move onto a base camp space aren’t discarded.
>   Instead, they are completely removed from the game. They won’t be used
>   again this game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BGG Answers](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1945684/native-discarded-when-moving-base-camp): (Majority View)

The native Card is NOT discarded. It ignores the Base Camp requirement like any other hex.

> If the native should **not** ignore base camps it should’ve been stated explicitely in the rules. It isn’t. Therefore the native may move onto base camps (without trashing/removing any card) like onto any other hex (except mountains and occupied ones).

-

> > ... If the native should **not** ignore ...
>
> "Ignore that space’s requirements and just place your piece on it" **overrides** the need to have such rule. This is how rulebooks work, from my 10 years of gaming experience.

-

> The Native does indeed ignore any and all symbols or requirements.
>   It lets you move onto an adjacent hex if that move is legal (i.e. no mountain and no occupied hex, unless you have the cave tile that specifically allows that).
>
> - If it is a base camp you don't trash cards
> - if it is rubble you don't discard cards
> - if it is terrain you don't need the shown strength.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the card indeed can fully ignore the Base Camp requirement. The other answer already referred to a number of interpretations of the base rule from which this follows.

The [official rule book](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/fc/6a/fa-the-quest-for-el-dorado-rulebook.pdf) also gives an example which seems to confirm this (IMHO). On page 6:

> Next, she plays the Native and moves her piece onto the rubble space. The Native allows her to ignore a space’s requirements, which means she doesn’t have to play 3 cards from her hand.

In this example, a rubble space was used as the target, but it seems logical to assume the same applies to a base camp as well. Both hex spaces have a requirement regarding cards, and here it is explicitly confirmed that the Native may ignore such a requirement.